# Python MySQL AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, attributes, execute

I am trying to retrieve data from tables in MySQL on Python. But I have received

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

My code is:

```
import mysql.connector as sqltor
mycon=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd=" ",database="revision")
if mycon.is_connected():
    print("Successfully Connected to MySQL database.")
else:
    print("Check yo inputs, they really correct?")

cursor=mycon.cursor
cursor.execute("select*from account")
```

Output:

```
Successfully Connected to MySQL database.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/biina/Documents/Python/Apparel store/Python/Practical File/Interface_Python_with_MySQL.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("select*from account")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: Can you clean up your post a bit? There should be an "edit" button and the interface when asking a question should also explain how to format code, for example.

Comment: I did not double check the structure after posting so thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Already fixed that for you. Don't know if the changes have been approved already.

Comment: Hi there, I have approved the suggestion so the post looks perfect from my view, I hope its the same for others. Im new here so thank you for fixing it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337452/mysqldb-raises-execute-first-error-even-though-i-execute-before-calling-fetc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the cursor function. So replace `cursor=mycon.cursor` with `cursor=mycon.cursor()`